# What is the difference between these loops?

Tags: c, stdio, putchar

I am a beginner of C programming.
I am learning C by "The C programming language second edition"(by Brain W.Kerninghan and Dennis M.Ritchie)
In the book I am stack with the exercise 1-10.
"Write a program to copy its input to its output, replacing each tab by `\t`, each backspace by `\b`, and each backslash by `\\`. This makes tabs and backspaces visible in an unambiguous way."

I wrote a program like this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;
    
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == '\t') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
        }
        if (c == '\b') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
        }
        if (c == '\\') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
        }
        else {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }
}
```

but this works weirdly.
Like below.

```
C:\C>gcc Replace2.c
C:\C>a 
tab     is      like    this 
tab\t   is\t    like\t  this
```

And on the Internet I found the program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int c, d;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        d = 0;
        if (c == '\\') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('\\');
            d = 1;
        }
        if (c == '\t') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('t');
            d = 1;
        }
        if (c == '\b') {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar('b');
            d = 1;
        }
        if (d == 0)
            putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And this works quite well.

```
C:\C>gcc Replace2.c
C:\C>a
tab     is      like    this
tab\tis\tlike\tthis
```

I wonder why these works differenly.
Could someone  tell me?

Comment: It seems in the first example the space between tab\t and is\t is different from that of like\t and this. 
This is strange because if putchar(c) puts tab it should be equal.

Comment: You should replace all of your `if` with `else if`, except for the first one. I believe then your program will work as desired.

Comment: Kernighan & Ritchie (2ed) anticipates C89, which itself is obsolete.  The current version is C17, and very soon will be C23.  I can't recommend using K&R as a textbook for learning C today.

Answer (score 0):

The last `else` in your code is attached only to the last `if` statement. So only if the last `if` statement's condition is false (i.e. the input character is not a backslash), it will take the `else` route and print the character. So it pretty much prints everything except the backslash. In particular, it prints the tabs. That's why there are tabs still remaining in your output.

The first two `if` statements in your code are independent of that `else`. If their conditions are not met, the execution just skips their brackets and continues afterwards. If you want to skip the character once a tab or backslash character is detected in the input, you can either convert every `if` (except the first one) into `else if` (as Andreas Wenzel suggested), or issue a `continue` instruction right before the closing bracket in each of those blocks after `if`, to skip all the remaining code in its body and enter the next round of the loop.